# Excel Formula - SUM LEFT on non-blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, sum, formula

In the following table at `column E`, I'm trying to extract the number before parentheses (which is `4 and 5` here) and then return the total summation on extracted values (which is `4 + 5 = 9` here)

The main problem is that the `LEFT` function can't handle blank cells, So I combined it with the `IF` function to replace blank cells with "0". But somehow the `LEFT` function replaces "0" with blank again and it doesn't work.

Any suggestion for proper formula to "*sum left number in column*"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below approach to bypass the error.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT("0"&E23:E25,FIND("(",E23:E25&"(")))`

Here we prefix the numbers with 0 which has no effect on value per your data and then we suffix the data with extra "(" which works for blank cells when searching using `FIND` function.

Comment: Nice use of concatention =)

Comment: Thanks @JvdV, I had first seen this on MrExcel (I think it was moderator named Peter_SSs), have used it once in a while instead of error function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(LEFT(E23:E25,FIND("(",E23:E25)-1),0))
```

[image]

Comment: This solution just returns the extracted numbers, not the sum of them. But thanks for your collaboration, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65652384/13836545

Comment: @AliTabaraei. I think you may have implemented it wrongly as it would perfectly sum all returned numbers. Either way; You got an answer so that's good.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT extracts the number from your cell as text. To convert it back to a number, you can use the VALUE function.

Taking your example. the following formula works for me:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(E23:E25="",0,VALUE(LEFT(E23:E25,1))))
```

A warning: this will only work for single digits because it takes the first character in the cell. You could add some if statements to check if there are spaces following the first character if you need to consider numbers greater than 10 for this formula.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work either. There is still a problem with blank cells. Thanks for your collaboration, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65652384/13836545